# How to post AES256 NSData to server using MKNetworKit?

Tags: aes, mknetworkkit

The username has been encrypted via [RNCryptor](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor) and I would like to send the encrypted username to server using the [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit). The encrypted username is in NSData format. But the MKNetworkKit seems not supporting the formats for the post body except NSDictionary. 
So I follow the suggestion of using setCustomPostDataEncodingHandler to post the encrypted username. But it crashed. Please help review if something wrong in my below codes.

```
NSMutableDictionary * postDataDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:username forKey:@"username"];


MKNetworkOperation *op = [self operationWithPath:@"URLtomyserver/login.php"
                                          params:postDataDict
                                           httpMethod:@"POST"];

[op setCustomPostDataEncodingHandler:^NSString *(NSDictionary *postDataDict) {
    NSData * username= [postDataDict objectForKey:@"username"];

    NSString * postString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:username encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return postString

} forType:@"application/json"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MKNetworkOperation *op = [self operationWithPath:INIT_URL params:body httpMethod:@"POST" ssl:YES];
[op setPostDataEncoding:MKNKPostDataEncodingTypeJSON];//This is important
[op addCompletionHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation)
```